# Why can I set the value of a private class attribute with getter in Java?

Tags: java, class, encapsulation

I'm new to Java and I wonder why it is possible to set the value of a private attribute this way, without using a setter ? :

```
class Example {
   private int[] thing;
   public void initialize() {
       thing = new int[10];
   }
   public int[] getThing() { 
       return thing;
   }
}
class myclass {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Example e = new Example();
       e.initialize();
       e.getThing()[0] = 1;
       System.out.println(e.getThing()[0]) // value is still 1...
}
```

I really do not understand why this is legal...

Edit: I expected e.getThing() to return the value of thing not a reference to thing and even if it was the case, as "thing" is private I thought I wont be able to modify it directly.

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the value to the **private member of other class** ?

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Comment: If you want to make thing read only I would do this in one of two ways. 1) make a defensive copy of the array, where I create another array with `new` and return this one. 2) Uses a List (eg. ArrayList<Integer>) instead and return an `Iterable` (which is an interface implemented by all lists). The only thing that can be done with an `Iterable` is iterating more or less, (though it is possible to modify the objects in the iterable if they are aggregates).

Comment: @patrik thx. I wanted 'thing' not to be modified without a setter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're exposing the reference to an array from the getter, and the array contents themselves are *mutable* i.e. you can change them. So in your example above you return a reference to the array held by the private variable in the class, you amend that array, and that change will be visible via the getter going forwards because it always returns that modified array.

To avoid this, what you *could* do is either:

1. return a read-only view of the collection via your getter. This could be fast, but if the parent object changes the array contents under you whilst you're (say) iterating over it, then this could be confusing
2. return a *defensive copy* via your getter. This would mean returning a new array copy per call, and this wouldn't change under you, but you pay a cost in copying it for each call

In your *specific* example above, you could create a read-only collection within your `initialize()` method, and then you're not going to have this issue.

I think you need to be clear re. *private* (i.e. the reference variable is not available outside the class) and *mutable* (the object you're returning can change). These are two very different concepts.

Comment: thx. I thought e.getThing() would return the value of thing not its reference in memory allowing it to be modified directly, eventually bypassing any setter.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int[] thing;
```

says that the reference to `thing` is private and therefor cannot be accessed from outside the class. Fortunately, you have a getter so you get the reference.

As arrays are mutable, you can modify the content of the array.

What you **can't** do is to set new `thing`:

```
e.thing = new int[5];
```

and this is what *private* does.

Comment: You haven't explained why `initialize` is able to assign the variable a value even when called from another class. That's the question.

Comment: I'm not it is, is it ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew what do you mean?

Comment: @nvioli that´s not the question, the question is why the value `1` is present at index `0` when he did let `getThing` return the reference to the array, as OP probably thinks it´s returning a copy of the array due to it beeing `private` or something like that (it´s actually unknown why and what he thinks is happening, but that´s my interpretation of his comment inside the code snippet).

Comment: @xenteros - I'm replying to nvioli

Answer (score 0):

This is because private members are directly accessible only in class they are defined, you can not access them outside of the class unless you provide some public accessor method. You are providing a public accessor to an array reference and after getting the reference you are changing the values

Answer (score -2):

The fact that `thing` is private means you can't

```
Example e = new Example();
e.thing = new int[10];
```

However, you've chosen to expose `initialize` publicly, so you can call it from another class. The implementation details of `initialize` are knowable only to the author of the `Example` class. That author may do whatever he or she wants within that class, including doing anything he or she wants with `private` fields.

Comment: Still you did not anser the question.

Comment: I thought the confusion was about the ability to set a `private` field from outside the class so that's what I answered; maybe I misunderstood what OP was confused about.

Comment: I believe so. The question is why you can change the values of the array *despite* the field being `private`.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. If I delete the initialize() method then declare thing with private int[] thing = new int[10]

Comment: @erebos007 assuming you're talking about doing it from another class, that _will not work_ because `thing` is private, meaning no other class has access to it. However, `initialize` is local to the `Example` class, so it has access to `thing` despite `thing` being private.